# What is the difference between StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey and STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey?

Tags: stripe-payments

I know this might seem like a simple question but I haven't found any answers in the documentation. Can someone please explain the difference between `StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey` and `STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey`. When are they used and for what specifically?

I'm new to coding so any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StripeAPI` is the top-level class that imports the rest of the Stripe iOS SDK.  [The documentation explains the `defaultPublishableKey` property on `StripeAPI`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/StripeAPI.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)StripeAPI(cpy)defaultPublishableKey):

> Set this to your Stripe publishable API key, obtained from https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys. Set this as early as possible in your application’s lifecycle, preferably in your AppDelegate or SceneDelegate. New instances of STPAPIClient will be initialized with this value. @warning Make sure not to ship your test API keys to the App Store! This will log a warning if you use your test key in a release build.

`STPAPIClient`, on the other hand, is the class/singleton you use to make Stripe API requests.  The `shared` property on this class is the singleton, and the `publishableKey` property on that singleton defaults to the value of `StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey`.  You can, however, change it if you need to make a request with a different key, although doing so would be an uncommon edge case.

You can [read more about `STPAPIClient`, including the properties mentioned above in Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAPIClient.html).